# Material Design Lite page resetting to page top when loading

Tags: material-design

I have a page using Google's Material Design Lite framework. If you start scrolling before the page loads, the page will snap back to the top once the page finishes loading.

This happens on many of the MDL sample sites too. Here's one example - https://getmdl.io/templates/android-dot-com/index.html

How can this effect be removed?

[image]